# Binding entire object with converter to text

Tags: c#, binding, converters, windows-phone

I have a ListBox with a the entire bound object being passed in to the converter (needed), and the object doesn't seem to be updating correctly. Here's the relevant XAML

```
<TextBlock
          Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource DueConverter}}" 
          FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" 
          Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" />
```

And the Converter

```
public class DueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return null;
        Task task = (Task)value;
        if (task.HasReminders)
        {
            return task.Due.Date.ToShortDateString() + " " + task.Due.ToShortTimeString();
        }
        else
        {
            return task.Due.Date.ToShortDateString();
        }
    }

    //Called with two-way data binding as value is pulled out of control and put back into the property
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And finally the due DateTime from the data model.

```
private DateTime _due;

    [Column(CanBeNull=false)]
    public DateTime Due
    {
        get { return _due; }
        set
        {
            if (_due != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("Due");
                _due = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Due");
            }
        }
    }
```

The NotifyPropertyChanging/Changed work, because other controls bound to different properties update correctly.

My goal is to have the due date TextBlock update whenever Due is changed, but the format of the output is dependent on another property of the Task object.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Generally, the SO protocol is to not put tags in the question title.  I've updated your title and re-tagged the question.

Answer (score 0):

The TextBlock.Text property is bound to a Task instance, it doesn't care about "Due". Whenever you change the value of "Due" you also need to raise the property changed event for "Task", for that binding to update itself.

Comment: How would I do that? Shouldn't it be raised automatically with the function `private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }` in the datacontext?

Comment: If you bind to properties such as "Due", it will, since the code calls NotifyPropertyChanged in the setter. But in your code you bind directly to an instance of Task and not its properties. It depends on how you bind against the Task instance, but you have to raise the NotifyPropertyChanged("name_of_your_task_property") in your code, whenever you want the Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource DueConverter}}" to update itself. How do you create/set the data that are being used as ItemsSource for the ListBox?